# Spring webclient onErrorReturn for specific type of exception

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I wanted to return a fallback value from webclient after retries for only specific type of exception. I tried the below code but it doesnt return the fallback value.

```
 public Mono<String> getEmployee(String request) {
    return WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .uri("/accounts/" + request)
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                if (clientResponse.statusCode().value() == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
                if (clientResponse.statusCode().value() == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
                    return clientResponse
                            .bodyToMono(String.class);
                }
                return Mono.error(new IllegalCallerException());
            })
            .retryWhen(Retry.max(3).filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof IllegalStateException))
            .onErrorReturn(IllegalStateException.class, "TECHNICAL_ERROR")
            .log();
}
```

As you see above, when Http status is 500, i wanted to retry only for IllegalStateException  for 3 times and return fallback value when exception type is IllegalStateException. I used onErrorReturn with fallback value and specific error to match. But above code doesn't work, it retries for 3 times but fallback value is not returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like that the best option for finding an issue is checking the instance of errors in debugger.

After all of retry tries are exhausted RetryExhaustedException will be throwed

Simple example for visualization:

```java
Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("example"))
                .retryWhen(Retry.max(-1))
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    assert Objects.equals(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName(), "RetryExhaustedException");
                })
                .subscribe();
```

Summary:

Your retry mechanism works but after there are exhausted it is not IllegalStateExcpetion

If you want to handle logic on IllegalStateException later you can use onErtryExhaustedThrow method like:

```java
.retryWhen(Retry.max(3)
   .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof IllegalStateException)
   .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retrySpec, retrySignal) -> new IllegalStateException()))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It worked after i used onRetryExhaustedThrow and throwed error which i match in onErrorReturn

Comment: Ye it may be solved like that, gonna update the answer with this

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following. I have similar code in our service and it is working as expected.

```java
public Mono<String> getEmployee(String request) {
    return WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .uri("/accounts/" + request)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, res -> {
                return Mono.error(new IllegalStateException());
            })
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .retryWhen(
                Retry.max(3)
                    .filter(IllegalStateException.class::isInstance)
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retrySpec, retrySignal) -> new MaxRetryAchievedException("Max retried"))
            ).onErrorReturn(MaxRetryAchievedException.class, "Techinal Error")
            .log();
}


public class MaxRetryAchievedException extends RuntimeException {

    public MaxRetryAchievedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you set the fallback value after retries?

Comment: Edited answer to make it return fallback value after max retries.